# Normal subsets of a Sylow p subgroup are conjugate if and only if they are $N_G(P)$ conjugate.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, sylow-theory

The following is a question from Dummit & Foote.

> Prove that if $U$ and $W$ are normal subsets of a Sylow $p$-subgroup
>   $P$ of a finite group $G$ then $U$ is $G$-conjugate to $W$ if and only
>   if $U$ is $N_G(P)$-conjugate to $W$.

Ofcourse G-conjugate means, there exists a $g 
\in G$ such that $gUg^{-1}=W$, and for $N_G(P)$ conjugate the element is restricted to $N_G(P)$.

The reverse implication is obvious. But I havent been able to prove the implication. D&F gives the hint that $N_P(U)=N_P(W)=P$, but I have not idea how this can be used to get information about $N_G(P)$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Normal *subsets*!!? :-)

Comment: @BabakSorouh "Normal subset" means a subset closed under conjugation.

Comment: @BabakSorouh: Yes. That's what the question says. The internet defines normal subsets as http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_subset

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a sketch, there are a few details left out for you to fill in:

1. Assume $gUg^{-1} = W$ for some $g \in G$.
2. Show that $gPg^{-1} \subseteq N_G(W)$.
3. Use the Sylow theorems to get that $xgPg^{-1}x^{-1} = P$ for some $x \in N_G(W)$.
4. Observe that $xg \in N_G(P)$ and $xgUg^{-1}x^{-1} = W$.

Comment: Thanks! I have worked through the steps. But please could you provide me some motivation or insight on the logical flow that lead you to the solution. I am finding it a bit hard to justify the steps. For e.g. Why did you try to look for a subset of $N_G(W)$, and how did you come with $gPg^{-1}$. If it is obvious then i I excessively dumb.

Comment: I think it is impossible for me to have solved this, even if I put a day into it.

Comment: I was plying around with the general formula $xN_G(H)x^{-1} = N_G(xHx^{-1})$ when I got $gPg^{-1} \subseteq N_G(W)$.  After that it's a common tactic to use the fact that if you have a tower $P \subseteq H \subseteq G$ and $P$ is a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$ then it is also a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $H$.  This is the only theorem I could imagine allows to to choose a conjugating element in a smaller subgroup.

Comment: @user23238 I solved most of the problems in that section (I only skipped some of the "prove there are no simple groups of order 1464754547" ones) and none took longer than an hour or so. I tried to figure this one out for two days before finally looking here.

Comment: I was quick to think of 1, 2, and 3, but I labelled $gPg^{-1}$ as $P'$, and that was so fixed in my mind that I forgot $xP'x = xgPg^{-1}x^{-1}$. Thank you.